# How to assign a variable to a dict saved on a text file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, text

As a beginner, I'm trying to write a contacts list program using a dict saved on a text file called contacts.txt to store the data in. In order to update my contacts dict I can use contacts.update(dict2), dict2 being the input data for a new contact. Ive tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
new_entry = {}
# contacts = {}


contacts = contacts_file = open("contacts.txt", 'a+')

def data(): 
    cell = input("Enter cell number: ")
    first = input("Enter first name: ")
    last = input("Enter last name: ")

    new_entry = {cell: (first, last)}
    print("NEW ENTRY:" + str(new_entry))

data()

contacts.update(new_entry)
print("CONTACTS: " + str(contacts))


def write_to_file():
    contacts_file = open("contacts.txt", 'w')
    contacts_file.write(str(contacts))
    contacts_file.close()

write_to_file()
```

My thinking is to assign the variable "contacts" to a dict saved on the text file. Initially the dict will be empty but it will be populated with new data every time new contact details are entered.

But I get an error: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'update' when I run the program.

Clearly the problem lies here:

```
contacts = contacts_file = open("contacts.txt", 'a+')
```

I want to assign the dictionary on the text file to variable contacts so that contacts is updated by new_entry and the updated contacts dict is saved to the text file again, over writing the original dict.

If I assign contacts to an empty dict it also doesn't work because the new data just gets added to an empty dictionary every time the program runs.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Andre

Comment: "I want to assign the dictionary on the text file" - there _is_ no dictionary in the text file. There only are a bunch of symbols which you have to _parse_ to extract the structure out of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `dict` (or any other Python object) in a file. You may have a string representation of it. You need to open the file, deserialize the object, update it, then serialize it and write it back to the file. For example, using `json`:

```
import json

with open('some_file') as f:
    deserialized_object = json.load(f)
    deserialized_object['key_to_update'] = 'updated_value'
    serialized_object = json.dumps(deserialized_object)

    f.seek(0)
    f.write(serialized_object)
    f.truncate()
```